# Custom Theme Class and Theme Structure in Vaadin 14

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I created a custom theme as an jar file and imported it into my project using annotation `@Theme(themeFolder = "basetheme")`. The structure of the theme is as follows

[image]

I also added dependencies to the pom.xml file. **This way everything works great.**

When I create my [custom BaseTheme class](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/styling/creating-a-custom-theme-class), then my styles from the custom theme and the standard styles from the lumo theme are not imported.

```
public class BaseTheme implements AbstractTheme
{

 @Override
    public String getBaseUrl()
    {
        return "/src/";
    }

    @Override
    public String getThemeUrl()
    {
        return "/themes/basetheme/";
    }
 }
```

What needs to be changed or added to make the custom theme work with a custom class?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue when I wrote my first theme.

Add a `theme.json` file to your `basetheme` folder. The documentation for this can be found [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/styling/custom-theme-configuration), but is lacking and doesn't discuss the following:

If you want your theme to include Lumo styles, you have to list them in `lumoImports`. E.g.,

```json
{
  "lumoImports": [
    "badge",
    "color",
    "sizing",
    "spacing",
    "style,
    "typography"
    ...
  ]
}
```

You can see how `lumoImports`'s value is used [theme-generator.js](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/blob/bba8d7028ebcad30da033e2a4e7c68dbf3d9f43e/flow-server/src/main/resources/plugins/application-theme-plugin/theme-generator.js#L136).

> ```js
> const lumoImports = themeProperties.lumoImports || ["color", "typography"];
> if (lumoImports && lumoImports.length > 0) {
>   lumoImports.forEach((lumoImport) => {
>     imports.push(`import '@vaadin/vaadin-lumo-styles/${lumoImport}.js';\n`);
>   });
>
>   lumoCssCode.push(`// Lumo styles are injected into shadow roots.\n`)
>   lumoCssCode.push(`// For the document, we need to be compatible with flow-generated-imports and add missing <style> tags.\n`)
>   lumoCssCode.push(`const shadowRoot = (target instanceof ShadowRoot);\n`)
>   lumoCssCode.push(`if (shadowRoot) {\n`);
>   lumoImports.forEach((lumoImport) => {
>     lumoCssCode.push(`injectGlobalCss(getStyleModule("lumo-${lumoImport}"), target, true);\n`);
>   });
>
>   lumoCssCode.push(`} else if (!document['${lumoCssFlag}']) {\n`);
>   lumoImports.forEach((lumoImport) => {
>     lumoCssCode.push(`addStyleInclude("lumo-${lumoImport}", target);\n`);
>   });
>   lumoCssCode.push(`document['${lumoCssFlag}'] = true;\n`);
>   lumoCssCode.push(`}\n`);
> }
> ```

The strings in `lumoImports` are matched literally to the JavaScript files in the root directory of the `vaadin-lumo-styles` package. See more [here](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-lumo-styles/tree/1.6).

By the way, `theme-generator.js` is what's creating `basetheme.generated.js` in your `basetheme` directory. You can check to make sure adding `lumoImports` worked by looking at this file. The end of the file should look something like this:

```js
  const shadowRoot = (target instanceof ShadowRoot);
  if(shadowRoot) {
    injectGlobalCss(getStyleModule("lumo-badge"), target, true);
    injectGlobalCss(getStyleModule("lumo-color"), target, true);
    injectGlobalCss(getStyleModule("lumo-sizing"), target, true);
    injectGlobalCss(getStyleModule("lumo-spacing"), target, true);
    injectGlobalCss(getStyleModule("lumo-style"), target, true);
    injectGlobalCss(getStyleModule("lumo-typography"), target, true);
  } else if(!document['_vaadinthemelumoimports_']) {
    addStyleInclude("lumo-badge", target);
    addStyleInclude("lumo-color", target);
    addStyleInclude("lumo-sizing", target);
    addStyleInclude("lumo-spacing", target);
    addStyleInclude("lumo-style", target);
    addStyleInclude("lumo-typography", target);
    document['_vaadinthemelumoimports_'] = true;
  }

}
```

Also, on the topic of those generated files, make sure it is not packaged with your build. See more [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/styling/custom-theme-packaging).

Comment: Adding a theme.json file didn't help me. Do you also use a Custom Theme Class? If so, what does the structure of your theme look like? What do I have to do to get the file basetheme.generated.js generated?

Comment: Sorry that it didn't work. No, I actually have never needed to use a theme class. If I did, I would probably want to ensure Lumo themes are included. So, I would add a `@JsModule("@vaadin/vaadin-lumo-styles/color.js")` for each style JS file on the theme class. The `basetheme.generated.js` should be generated when you run your application.